# Sum per week day is not right

Tags: javascript

I have 2 problems with this code, 1st one is that for the user `Edgar Francisco Williams Britez` is showing the wrong values for monday, wednesday and friday like this

```
Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
10       0       0
```

It should display like this

```
Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
         0
```

values for user `FREDY RAMON BAEZ OCAMPOS` are displaying correctly but then it should sum the total of each user per day but is not doing that correctly.
The Total it displays like this

```
Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
10       0       0
```

expected result:

```
 Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
 10      2       0
```

So that at the end the table it's supposed to look like this:

```
User                               Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
FREDY RAMON BAEZ OCAMPOS           10      2       0
Edgar Francisco Williams Britez            0        
Totals                             10      2       0
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong to be honest, if anyone can give me some help

```js
const myObj = {
  "data": {
    "1660": {
      "3": {
        "1": {
          "RC": 10,
          "time": "Entrada: 07:40:26\nSalida: 17:18:45\n",
          "distance": "Entrada: 45 mts\nSalida: 41 mts\n",
          "RCNP": 10,
          "RCP": 0,
          "status": "5"
        },
        "3": {
          "RC": 2,
          "time": "Entrada: 07:46:17\n",
          "distance": "Entrada: 44 mts\n",
          "RCNP": 1,
          "RCP": 1,
          "status": "1"
        },
        "5": {
          "RC": 0,
          "time": "",
          "distance": "",
          "RCNP": 0,
          "RCP": 0,
          "status": "0"
        }
      },
      "total": {
        "1": {
          "RC": 10,
          "time": "",
          "distance": "",
          "RCNP": 10,
          "RCP": 0
        },
        "3": {
          "RC": 2,
          "time": "",
          "distance": "",
          "RCNP": 1,
          "RCP": 1
        },
        "5": {
          "RC": 0,
          "time": "",
          "distance": "",
          "RCNP": 0,
          "RCP": 0
        }
      }
    },
    "1941": {
      "3": {
        "3": {
          "RC": 0,
          "time": "Entrada: 16:19:15\nSalida: 16:19:17\n",
          "distance": "Entrada: 6602879 mts\nSalida: 6602879 mts\n",
          "RCNP": 0,
          "RCP": 0,
          "status": "5"
        }
      },
      "total": {
        "3": {
          "RC": 0,
          "time": "",
          "distance": "",
          "RCNP": 0,
          "RCP": 0
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "error": false,
  "userData": {
    "1660": "FREDY RAMON BAEZ OCAMPOS",
    "1941": "Edgar Francisco Williams Britez"
  }
}

loadResumeForAuditor(myObj);

function loadResumeForAuditor(resultMap) {
  let tableResume = document.getElementById("tableResume"); //id de la tabla
  let trResume = document.getElementById('trResume'); //id del tr
  let trCloned;
  let footer = document.getElementById("tfootContainer"); //id tfoot totales

  var eventTypeSelect = jQuery('input[name="customRadio"]:checked').attr("id");

  //console.log(resultMap.data);
  for (const [userId, weekValue] of Object.entries(resultMap.data)) {
    trCloned = trResume.cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementsByClassName("group-auditor")[0].innerText = resultMap.userData[userId];
    document.getElementsByClassName('tBodyContainer')[0].appendChild(trCloned);
    for (const [key, summaryData] of Object.entries(weekValue)) {
      if (key == "total") {
        for (const [dayOfWeek, totalValue] of Object.entries(summaryData)) {
          document.getElementsByClassName("total-day-" + dayOfWeek)[0].innerText = totalValue[eventTypeSelect];
          //console.log(totalValue[eventTypeSelect]);
        }
      } else {
        for (const [dayOfWeek, resumeValue] of Object.entries(summaryData)) {
          let tdColor = jQuery("#legendTable td[id='" + resumeValue["status"] + "']").attr("class");
          document.getElementsByClassName("resume-day-" + dayOfWeek)[0].innerText = resumeValue[eventTypeSelect];
          //console.log(resumeValue[eventTypeSelect]);
          jQuery(document.getElementsByClassName("resume-day-" + dayOfWeek)[0]).parent('td').attr('class', tdColor);
          document.getElementsByClassName('tBodyContainer')[0].appendChild(trCloned);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="border p-2 rounded">
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="RC" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input" checked="">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="RC">Cantidad de Romaneos</label>
  </div>

  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="distance" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="distance">Distancia Entrada / Salida</label>
  </div>

  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="time" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="time">Horario Entrada / Salida</label>
  </div>

  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="RCP" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="RCP">Fiscalización Presencial</label>
  </div>

  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="RCNP" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="RCNP">Fiscalización No Presencial</label>
  </div>
</div>

<table id="tableResume" class="table-sm table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap w-100">
  <thead style="width:100%">
    <th>User</th>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
    <th>Saturday</th>
    <th>Sunday</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="tBodyContainer">
    <tr id="trResume">
      <td><span class="group-auditor"></span></td>
      <td class="bg-white"><span class="resume-day-1"></span></td>
      <td class="bg-white"><span class="resume-day-2"></span></td>
      <td class="bg-white"><span class="resume-day-3"></span></td>
      <td class="bg-white"><span class="resume-day-4"></span></td>
      <td class="bg-white"><span class="resume-day-5"></span></td>
      <td class="bg-white"><span class="resume-day-6"></span></td>
      <td class="bg-white"><span class="resume-day-0"></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot id="tfootContainer">
    <th>Totals</th>
    <th><span class="total-day-1"></span></th>
    <th><span class="total-day-2"></span></th>
    <th><span class="total-day-3"></span></th>
    <th><span class="total-day-4"></span></th>
    <th><span class="total-day-5"></span></th>
    <th><span class="total-day-6"></span></th>
    <th><span class="total-day-0"></span></th>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO What you are doing wrong is mixing the data processing with the presentation. [Those are separate concerns](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html)

IOW: always write test cases of your data processing first, then worry about presentation later. TDD is an awesome discipline to make sure you get what you want long before your project is put into production.

This is a test that I wrote using your object as base.

The result I got using `console.log( report )` was:

```
 [
  {
    name: 'FREDY RAMON BAEZ OCAMPOS',
    days: { '1': 10, '3': 2, '5': 0 }
  },
  { name: 'Edgar Francisco Williams Britez', days: { '3': 0 } }
]
```

and the `console.log( totals )`

```
{ '1': 10, '3': 2, '5': 0 }
```

test code:

```
class SO_Test extends Test {
test_1(){
    const obj  = {
        "data": {
            "1660": {
                "3": {
                    "1": {
                        "RC": 10,
                        "time": "Entrada: 07:40:26\nSalida: 17:18:45\n",
                        "distance": "Entrada: 45 mts\nSalida: 41 mts\n",
                        "RCNP": 10,
                        "RCP": 0,
                        "status": "5"
                    },
                    "3": {
                        "RC": 2,
                        "time": "Entrada: 07:46:17\n",
                        "distance": "Entrada: 44 mts\n",
                        "RCNP": 1,
                        "RCP": 1,
                        "status": "1"
                    },
                    "5": {
                        "RC": 0,
                        "time": "",
                        "distance": "",
                        "RCNP": 0,
                        "RCP": 0,
                        "status": "0"
                    }
                },
                "total": {
                    "1": {
                        "RC": 10,
                        "time": "",
                        "distance": "",
                        "RCNP": 10,
                        "RCP": 0
                    },
                    "3": {
                        "RC": 2,
                        "time": "",
                        "distance": "",
                        "RCNP": 1,
                        "RCP": 1
                    },
                    "5": {
                        "RC": 0,
                        "time": "",
                        "distance": "",
                        "RCNP": 0,
                        "RCP": 0
                    }
                }
            },
            "1941": {
                "3": {
                    "3": {
                        "RC": 0,
                        "time": "Entrada: 16:19:15\nSalida: 16:19:17\n",
                        "distance": "Entrada: 6602879 mts\nSalida: 6602879 mts\n",
                        "RCNP": 0,
                        "RCP": 0,
                        "status": "5"
                    }
                },
                "total": {
                    "3": {
                        "RC": 0,
                        "time": "",
                        "distance": "",
                        "RCNP": 0,
                        "RCP": 0
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "error": false,
        "userData": {
            "1660": "FREDY RAMON BAEZ OCAMPOS",
            "1941": "Edgar Francisco Williams Britez"
        }
    };
    
    var users = obj.userData;
    var id_users = Object.keys( users );

    var totals = {};
    var report = [];
    id_users.forEach( function( id_user ){
        let second_level = Object.keys( obj.data[ id_user ] );
        let days = {};
        second_level.forEach( function( key3 ){
            if( key3 === "total" )
                return;
            var data = obj.data[ id_user ][key3];
            var dows = Object.keys( data );
            dows.forEach( function( dow ){
                if( days[ dow ] === undefined ){
                    days[ dow ] = 0;
                }
                if( totals[ dow ] === undefined ){
                    totals[ dow ] = 0;
                }
                let num = obj.data[ id_user ][key3][dow]["RC"];
                days[ dow ] += num;
                totals[ dow ] += num;
            })
        })
        let item_report = {};
        item_report.name = users[ id_user ];
        item_report.days = days;
        report.push( item_report );
        
        
    })
    
    console.log( report );
    console.log( totals );

    this.assertTrue( true );
    this.done();
}
}
```